# Error archiving or generating signed bundle of my App whereas it works fine in debug mode

Tags: xcode, react-native, android-studio

I am using react-native 0.61.5. For all the previous versions of my App, everything worked fine: I was running expo publish and then archiving the App on Xcode and generating a signed bundle on Android Studio. But spontaneously,  now I cannot archive or generate a signed bundle (the App is still working fine in debug mode).

[this is the error I get on iOS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSOyy.png)

[and on Android](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FXEWV.png)

I also try to re-open previous versions that I was able to publish fine but now they also have the same error.

Would someone understand what is happening? :)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Before making a release build, make sure you have run `expo publish` at least once

Comment: and it still does not work..

Answer (score 0):

Trying cleaning your build folder and trying again.
Sometimes there may be some form of file corruption or mismatch of data within the build folder, if not cleaned for a while.

Use `cd android`

Then `./gradlew clean`

For APK `./gradlew assembleRelease`

For AAB `./gradlew bundleRelease`

Try the equivalent for iOS within xCode.

Comment: I cleaned the project on iOS and Android but still got the same error...

Comment: Would you have any other idea?

Comment: Have you tried cleaning and building the project out in Android Studio, then running ./gradlew bundleRelease? I don't know why exactly but that fixes it sometimes for me.